Embed twitter (X) post in WordPress Elementor shows 403 error
I try to embed twitter post as HTML in Elementor page editor, but it cant save and shows 403 error.

When I try to do the same using classic editor it works well.
I dug a little and find out that the reason may be in another plugin - Wordfence - is a security plugin for WordPress sites
in the console there are errors for request to save page and in these messages contain infor that it is because of Wordfence


How can I "whitelist" adding twitter posts using Elementor?

Have you set the firewall status to learning mode, as suggested?

According to this article :

You can find the traffic that happens at the time you receive the 403
and whitelist that.


Try saving your post again
Go to WordFence
Click on Tools inside the WordFence menu
Click on Live Traffic. This view shows recent traffic to your site.
Filter the traffic to "Blocked By Firewall".
Click on the request you just made to save the page in your page builder -- it'll usually be the most recent request and from your general area
Double check that it was actually you making the request
Whitelist the request

